# Removed question - what are the rules

Tags: discussion, how-to-answer

Today one of my questions (Project Management and sales activities) was removed. 
I'm wondering why ?

What are the rules related to remove questions, because I think that i'm not fully understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Your original question wasn't deleted. Instead, your follow up question, which was posted as an answer, was removed.

During the PMSE Self-Eval this week, I noticed that your question titled [Project Management and sales activities](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/5646/project-management-and-sales-activities/) had another question that was posted as an answer to the original question.

**Questions Posted As Answers**:

The goal of StackExchange is to exist as a resource of knowledge, for years to come, in a structured Q&A format. There is a question, followed by a series of answers. The accepted answer appears at the top, followed by the remaining answers ordered from highest voted to lowest voted.

This pushes the most relevant content to the top of the page so it's easy to locate for future visitors.

If you see an answer posted that's not an answer, you can flag that post as "not an answer", which is visible to moderators in a flag queue.

In this case, I found the answer during the self-evaluation.

**Making Updates to Your Question:**

While it is okay to answer your own question on StackExchange sites, the answer posted should be an answer to the question. Instead, this appeared to me like a clarification of your question instead of an answer to the original question.

If you feel your question needs more clarification, you can always make an [edit](https://pm.stackexchange.com/posts/5646/edit) to that question to add more details. This bumps your question to the top of the active list so others will see your changes. You can also leave comments on answers, when appropriate, asking answers to review your edits to your question. This gives those users an opportunity to edit their answers to address your updates.

If you have a completely different question to ask, then you would ask the new question separately. This helps compartmentalize information so it's easily searchable on Google by keeping things concise.

Here is the [question posted as an answer](https://pm.stackexchange.com/a/5654/34). Since it's only visible to users with 2000 reputation, I've listed it below for reference:

> It's obvious to me that the PM is involved in some part of the sales process, such as making the valuation of production solutions, prepare a schedule, get information about the technical capabilities and resources. This's a substantive contribution to the offer, which gives a lot of knowledge about what is sold and when the project starts, PM knows what is going on, cause he took active part in the sales process.
>
> I meant for a situation where the PM takes responsibility for requirements analysis, preparation of all documents, negotiations with the client and manage the entire process of preparation.
>
> Because of his experience and knowledge of the situation in the company PM should actively participate in this process, but whether he should take responsibility for the overall preparation of the offer? Where should be the line ?

If you have any more questions, please let us know.

Comment: Thanks for answering. In my opinion it's not another question, but expanding oryginal one. But i undersand, that i should have used comment instead. I was suprised that i missed 10 of reputation assiciated with this answer. Now I know what happend. Thanks a lot for explanation.